Can we add syntax highlight in ubuntu default Text editor in markdown document type?
Ubuntu v 24.04
default text Editor support to set Document Type which is great and it support markdown upto some extent
so asking whether we can highlight the syntax writing written within code syntax using back ticks and language name such as
```sh 
something  
```

